# Can scikit-multilearn handle multi-target regression task?

Tags: scikit-multilearn

I would like to know whether scikit-multilearn can handle multiple-output regression task. If not, can you recommend another tool that provides a wide range of algorithms for evaluation?

Thank you,
Bundit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scikit-learn most definitely supports this. There is a 'multioutput' module that implements a variety of estimators and the 'MultiOutputRegressor' specifically should be right on the nose for your needs here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor